# USB not working on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, kernel, usb-drive, webcam, fdisk

The USB ports in my notebook don't work for my kindle and my pen driver. For my cellphone, they work for some reason. I tried running `fdisk -l` and all the `sdb` partitions are missing. But if I run `lsusb` the device appears. The ports work normally on Debian and my webcam doesn't work too.

EDIT------

The kindle charges when plugged and I don't think the cable is the problem since it works on my Debian OS in the same computer. It also works for my cellphone.

```
Debian 9.3 64 bits
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits
Intel® Core™ i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
Intel® Haswell Mobile
Dell inspiron 15 serie 3000
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 1949:0004 Lab126, Inc. Amazon Kindle 3/4/Paperwhite
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Plese can you [edit] your question with info about notebook(brand, model), also specify your Ubuntu version(as at tag,like 19.10 or 18.04) and Debian version(in question).

Comment: Show us the complete output of `lsusb` in your question, preferably with the devices plugged in.

Comment: Does your kindle charge when plugged into a non-working USB port?

Comment: To answer the questions above, please click [edit] and put the answers into your question. Also, please try a different USB cable and let us know the result of that.